# How to discard unchecked changes in GIT repo

Tags: git

Initially I had created one repo in GIT repo and added some of the Angular code to master branch. However for my angular to work properly I had downloaded node_modules which had around 5000 files and now my visual studio code shows that I have 5000 untracked changes.
I deleted the dev and master branch from my GIT repo to fix it but as soon as I open Visual Studio code its showing me still same thing. I amended settings.json as well to disable GIT connection but it completely disabled connecting to GIT.

How to fix it?

screenshot.

[image: View of the VS Code]

Comment: Your question involves many technologies, and it is also very specific to your environment. Try to narrow it down: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your problem could likely be solved a number of ways, and it is unclear whether you seek a git-based solution, or a Visual Studio solution.

Comment: In terms of solving your problem, you could start by learning about ".gitignore" files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore (but in general, putting an entire other framework inside your own repository requires many careful considerations)

Answer (score 1):

add node_modules to .gitignore file.